# History API with Ajax (Single Page Application) and virtual urls

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, history.js

At the moment I do not have any script only a idea, but unsure, whether it is possible or not.

What I want to do:

I want to create a single page application with the ability, that the user can click back and forward (history api).

When the user visit the page the first time, than the content will loaded from the server.
If than he is clicking on another link I want to hide the content from the current page and display the content from the new target.

My questions:

1. Is that possible to do?
2. Is there maybe a example possible?
3. Why does History.js have a lot of "Adapters" like history.adapter.jquery.js?
4. Which technique do you use to hide large contents?
5. Do you have a recommendation to save, cache large contents for later display?

Comment: for single page application I always recommend to use `backbone.js`. It actually deals perfectly with the history. http://backbonejs.org/

Comment: thank you :), well ressource. why not ember.js instead couse ember is a mvc?

Comment: Both are cool, it's just a preference. Maybe the community of backbone.js is larger. It's up to you